# How to search Gmail to find conversations that are both in the Inbox AND have a specific Label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

How can I search Gmail so I view and *only* view **all** conversations that are both:

1. in the Inbox (e.g. not Archived), AND
2. have a specific Label

?

If I look at my Gmail inbox now and see a total of 160 conversations and manually count 60 of those 160 as having label "X" on them in the message list, then I want to do a search such that I only view those 60 "X" messages in the inbox so I can get through them one by one without having to worry about the other 100 conversations.

**UPDATE**

Find out the reason the answers below do not work.  [Labels are applied **per message**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?hl=en), not per conversation.  So if the first message of a conversation has label "X" applied to it, but replies to that same conversation do **not** get the "X" label applied to them, then the conversation will NOT show up when a new reply is received and you search for `in:inbox label:X` even though the conversation misleadingly displays the "X" label.  This becomes clear when you switch "Conversation View" to "off".  Replies to conversations do NOT automatically inherit the labels of the first message in the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `is:inbox label:test` will get you what you're looking for. For some reason the `is:inbox` isn't documented on the [search operators page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), but it should work.

Comment: That did not work.  It only showed me a subset (about 20 of the 60 conversations currently in the inbox that have the label).  Any other ideas?

Comment: Inbox in gmail actually is a label

Comment: @DDS: Yes, but this solution is not working.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl Try with **label:(inbox X)**

Comment: @DDS:  Unfortunately that also only shows the 20, not all 60.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You want mails with BOTH *X and inbox* ?  -> mail that, at same time, are classified as inbox and X, and only those [you loose the mail that has only X]

Comment: @DDS:  Yes.  I think my Gmail is corrupt.  Doing a search just for `in:inbox` shows 11,000 results instead of the 107 results in the inbox right now.  Furthermore, I applied a `TEMP` label to all e-mails with `X` label, and then did a search for `label:TEMP label:inbox` and I got the 60 e-mail results I needed instead of the 20 that show up under `label: X label:inbox`.  So my Labels and/or Gmail are corrupt.  How can I get this fixed?

Comment: In this case I'll say yes: contact gmail helpdesk (I think now is a sort of community that, if common solutions won't work, will redirect you to HD) and tell them your issues. Anyway, you can try using 'old style' html gmail and see if issue persists even on the old system. A work-around can be connecting a client like thunderbird and using it for searches.

Comment: @DDS: Can you please direct me to the Gmail Helpdesk you mentioned ?

Comment: You can try either https://support.google.com/mail/?hl=en#topic=7065107 or https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail

Also, are you running on the new Gmail look or the old Gmail look?

Comment: @plttn: I've tried it on both and the problem occurred on both versions.  The support.google.com page doesn't seem to have my issue or any way to get help.  Should I create a post in the productforums.google.com site?  Are they able to fix actual server-side bugs on consumer accounts?

Comment: And you're certain that the label you're searching for is on all emails? The likelihood of this being a server-side bug only affecting your account is close to zero. 

Is the label the same, is there a space after that you can't see and so forth? If you just search for the label, do you get all of those conversations.

Comment: "And you're certain that the label you're searching for is on all emails?" Yes as I can see it in the message list.  "Is the label the same" Yes.  "is there a space after that you can't see and so forth?" No. " If you just search for the label, do you get all of those conversations."  Yes, I believe so.  However, if I search for just `in:inbox` (or its equivalent `label:inbox`) I get thousands of messages instead of the 150 or so that are actually in the inbox.  This, together with the original problem is what leads me to believe my Gmail is corrupt.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Again, there's no real way for just your account to "corrupt". There's nothing different in the way your data is stored versus anyone else's data. Do you use IMAP or POP3 clients, because those can affect the handling of inbox/not inbox conversations.

Comment: Can we go on chat so you can assist with trouble-shooting in real-time to see if it's actually corrupt or not?

Answer (score 1):

You mean in the inbox(e.g. Not archived)?
Search **Label:inbox**

Have a specific label X?
search **Label:X**

Both those condition meet? Search **Label:inbox & Label:X**

You may try the advanced search , type the condition that you need,
and it will turn to the search pattern in search textfield

Comment: That did not work.  It only showed me a subset (about 20 of the 60 conversations currently in the inbox that have the label).  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not understand what you need exactly, if you have 40 conversations have label X, 20 conversations have label X and label inbox
And you want show those 60 conversations, why don't search Label X directly??

Comment: There are a lot more than 60 messages that have label "X" in my Gmail.  However, in the inbox, there are only 60 (plus 100 other e-mails without that label).  I want to only show those 60 and nothing else.  However, when I run the search `Label:inbox Label:X`, it only shows me 20, not all 60.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm confused, So other 40 mails show up in your inbox, but does not have label with "inbox"??

Comment: In the inbox, none of the 160 messages have the label `Inbox`.  I don't think Gmail displays the `Inbox` label when you are viewing the inbox.  However, if I click the Label X link, then I see all 60 do have the label `Inbox`.  However, when searching for `Label:inbox Label:X` only 20 of them show up, not all 60.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Any other ideas?